# Careers 2.0 - Privacy settings not immediately obvious

Tags: feature-request, jobs

This is more a usability-issue report than anything else - but I filled-out my SOC2.0 profile a couple of weeks ago and came back today and saw I still had no profile views. I searched around and found a few threads on Meta SO and saw a small reference to the Privacy setting. Ah-ha!

It turns out my profile was set to Private - and I noticed that it isn't a very obvious (at least to me). Can you make it more obvious? Maybe provide a diagnostics page "Why aren't people finding my profile?".